# How do I help my squash?

Tags: identification, squash

The leaves have yellow spots which might turn grey at some point. They also have small white eggs in the bottom side.

What is the likely culprit and how can I remove it or help my squash recover.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of squash is this? There does appear to be a cluster of dark-colored squash bug eggs near the top of the leaf in the first picture, but the white things do not appear to be squash bug eggs. Do the white things move? The damage doesn't look like squash bug damage. They might be aphid skins or something.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from the blurry picture, but the eggs look like eggs for a squash bug.

http://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/insects/find/squash-bugs/

I had some on my pumpkins this year and they killed several of my plants until I started catching and killing them. Hope that helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

After trimming some bad leaves off my plant those "egg sacks" when disrupted erupt into a powdery mildew. Getting a little deeper into the vine I can tell that this is the powdery mildew that kills the vine.